# Windows or Linux cluster

Tags: linux, windows, cluster

I'm thinking on making a computing cluster at home to render things that I do in 3d programs like blender, maya and UDK. can I use a linux cluster enen though UDK only runs on on windows or am I forced to use windows? if so can I make a linux cluster with a windows "master"?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> UDK only runs on on windows

And, you have your answer.

Comment: thanks i figured as much. would all the computers need to have windows installed or can they have no OS?. sorry I dont really understand how clusters work...

Comment: They need Windows installed. I think you should consider hiring a professional.

Comment: Ya I think I will even though I'm curious it seems like its a little complicated. thanks